# Obtener id de un formulario enviado

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo aplicacion que se llena mediante sesiones, y estoy tratando de obtener el id de el modelo Note cuando lo envio por el metodo post pero he intentado buscando por el request pensando que guardaba la informacion pero no, luego el mismo formulario que envie intente sacar el id pero no pude, pues el formulario no tiene el id en sus campos.

```
def add_book(request):
    template_name = 'books/create_note.html'
    book = get_or_create_book(request)
    form = NoteForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        note = Note.objects.get(pk=form.pk)
        book.notes.add(note)
        form.save()
        return redirect('books:book')
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form,
    })
```

este es el formulario

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = (
            'title', 'nota'
        )
        labels = {
            'title': 'Titulo',
            'nota': 'Nota',
        }
```

Este es mi modelo al cual esta con una foranea con el modelo Note

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(Note)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_id
```

he intentado instanciando los dos modelos y de ahi buscar el id, pero como el query set que hize no puede recivir el id me genera error, y pues no se guarda.

Comment: Quieres que al crear la nueva instancia del modelo `Note` relacionarla al modelo `Book` verdad? ademas de debería salir error no es así?

Comment: mas que crear una instancia quiero obtener el id del registro recien creado en el modelo para asi poder crear la sesion pero pues no se como hacer lo, pues cuando lo hago por instancia error que me devuelve es que le estoy retornando un objeto

Comment: Ya publique mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Comment: uf fue muy claro la respuesta, no tenia ni idea que se podia hacer eso con el formulario muchas gracias, estuve mucho tiempo con el error no podia darle solucion y gracias por dejarme claro lo de modelform y donde estudiarlo.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este punto de tu código

```
form = NoteForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    note = Note.objects.get(pk=form.pk)
    book.notes.add(note)
    form.save()
```

El form no tiene un atributo `pk`, después de todo **es un formulario y no la instancia**. Y de hecho debería dar error.

Al crear una instancia de un formulario, si dicho formulario no recibe una instancia pues el formulario la crea, y para acceder a ella seria de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> form.instance # Accedemos a la instancia
<Model: ...>
>>> form.instance.attr # Accedemos a un atributo de la instancia
...
>>> form.instance.attr = 1 # Podemos Modificar el atributo de la instancia
>>>
```

Ahora, si intentamos acceder al atributo `id`:

```
>>> form.instance.id 
>>> print(form.instance.id)
None
```

Como podrás darte cuenta **no existe el `id`**, y esto es porque aun no se a guardado el objeto en la base de datos, y **es necesario** que se guarde el objeto en la base de datos para que exista el `id`.

Entonces para obtener el `id` del objeto o registro ya creado seria así:

```
note = form.save()
note.id # <--
```

> Cabe recalcar que el método
>   [`ModelForm.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)
>   **retorna el objeto ya guardado en la base de datos**.

Y listo así obtienes el `id` del objeto o registro ya creado, o mejor dicho ya guardado en la base de datos.

---

Por otra parte, esta parte de tu código debería quedar así:

```
form = NoteForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    note = form.save()
    book.notes.add(note)
```

Espero haberte ayudado.